# How to customize telnet login prompt on linux

Tags: linux, authentication, telnet, pam, rhel6

I need to change "login:" string when i am connecting through telnet. Is.Is there any way to change in configuration file ?
e.g.: login as: need to change this string.

Comment: Related: [ServerFault: How to customize telnet login prompt on linux](http://serverfault.com/questions/319416/how-to-customize-telnet-login-prompt-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change it is via locale settings, as both of those strings are locale aware.

`Login:` is located in `/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo` and `Password:` is located in `/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo`

Comment: Thanks.I am not having that file .Instead i am having /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/redhat-dist.mo . Looks like it is a binary file. Can you please tell how to change in this file.